# How to achieve AJAX(interactive) kind of SEARCH in LINUX to FIND files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, sh

I am interested in typing a search keyword in the terminal and able to see the output `immediately` and `interactively`. That means, like searching in google, I want to get results immediately after every character or word keyed-in.

I tought of doing this by combining WATCH command and FIND command but unable to bring the interactivenes.

Lets assume, to search for a file with name 'hint' in filename, I use the command

```
$ find | grep -i hint
```

this pretty much gives me the decent output results.

But what I want is the same behaviour interactively, that means with out retyping the command but only typing the SEARCH STRING.

I tought of writing a shell script which reads from a STDIN and executes the above PIPED-COMMAND for every 1 sec. Therefore what ever I type it takes that as an instruction every time for the command. But WATCH command is not interactive.

I am interested in below kind of OUTPUT:

```
$ hi
./hi
./hindi
./hint

$ hint
./hint
```

If anyone can help me with any better alternative way instead of my PSUEDO CODE, that is also nice

Comment: Does it need to accept backspaces ?

Comment: Yes, instead of pressing ENTER key, simply typing or correcting by backspace. The program need to list the files as per the current (that second's) characters (in that string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stumbled aross this old question, found it interesting and thought I'd give it a try. This BASH script worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Set MINLEN to the minimum number of characters needed to start the    
# search. 
MINLEN=2
clear
echo "Start typing (minimum $MINLEN characters)..." 
# get one character without need for return 
while read -n 1 -s i
do
    # get ascii value of character to detect backspace
    n=`echo -n $i|od -i -An|tr -d " "`
    if (( $n == 127 )) # if character is a backspace...
    then 
        if (( ${#in} > 0 )) # ...and search string is not empty
        then 
            in=${in:0:${#in}-1} # shorten search string by one
            # could use ${in:0:-1} for bash >= 4.2 
        fi
    elif (( $n == 27 )) # if character is an escape...
    then
        exit 0 # ...then quit
    else # if any other char was typed... 
        in=$in$i # add it to the search string
    fi
    clear 
    echo "Search: \""$in"\"" # show search string on top of screen
    if (( ${#in} >= $MINLEN )) # if search string is long enough...
    then    
        find "$@" -iname "*$in*" # ...call find, pass it any parameters given
    fi
done
```

Hope this does what you intend(ed) to do. I included a "start dir" option, because the listings can get quite unwieldy if you search through a whole home folder or something. Just dump the `$1` if you don't need it. 
Using the ascii value in `$n` it should be easily possible to include some hotkey functionality like quitting or saving results, too.

EDIT:

If you start the script it will display "Start typing..." and wait for keys to be pressed. If the search string is long enough (as defined by variable `MINLEN`) any key press will trigger a `find` run with the current search string (the `grep` seems kind of redundant here). The script passes any parameters given to `find`. This allows for better search results and shorter result lists. `-type d` for example will limit the search to directories, `-xdev` will keep the search on the current file sytem etc. (see `man find`). Backspaces will shorten the search string by one, while pressing Escape will quit the script. The current search string is displayed on top. I used `-iname` for the search to be case-insensitive. Change this to `-name' to get case-sensitive behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the neat script. Is it possible to see the search string also when I type? And I found that its coming out of the script when I use backspace with error message " substring expression < 0". And please mention the usage also, they way you intended me to use it by giving detailed example by editing the answer. It would be a good value addition to your answer.

Comment: For some reason my bash version didn't give that error message. Wrapping the string shortening in an `if/then` should fix it anyway.

Comment: Excellent. Its looking great now. But I am still getting that error if I use backspace. My bash version is `4.1.2(1)-release`

Comment: I used 4.3 ( Ubuntu) and everything works fine... Just tested on a 4.1 (CentOS) and, yep, there's the error. OK, I'll see if I can fix it.

Comment: Ah. I see. The syntax `${in:0:-1}` with the negative length wasn't valid before Bash 4.2. Will have to use `${in:0:${#in}-1}` instead.

Comment: Awesome. You did it. Pleasure to meet you. It would be great if you update your twitter details, I would like to follow you :). I am available at JagadishTalluri.

Comment: Not twittering at all, so the profile's up-to-date actually... but thank you nonetheless. :)

Answer (score 1):

This code below takes input on `stdin`, a filtering method as a macro in `"$1"`, and outputs go to `stdout`.

You can use it e.g., as follows:

```
#Produce basic output, dynamically filter it in the terminal,
#and output the final, confirmed results to stdout
vi `find . | terminalFilter`
```

The default filtering macro is 
`grep -F "$pattern"`
the script provides the pattern variable as whatever is currently entered.
The immediate results as a function of what is currently entered are displayed on
the terminal. When you press `<Enter>`, the results become final
and are outputtted to `stdout`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

##terminalFilter

del=`printf "\x7f"` #backspace character

input="`cat`"       #create initial set from all input
#take the filter macro from the first argument or use
# 'grep -F "$pattern"'
filter=${1:-'grep -F "$pattern"'}  
pattern=  #what's inputted by the keyboard at any given time

printSelected(){
  echo "$input" | eval "$filter"
}
printScreen(){
  clear
  printSelected
  #Print search pattern at the bottom of the screen
  tput cup $(tput lines);  echo -n "PATTERN: $pattern"
} >/dev/tty   
#^only the confirmed results go `stdout`, this goes to the terminal only

printScreen
#read from the terminal as `cat` has already consumed the `stdin`
exec 0</dev/tty
while IFS=$'\n' read -s -n1 key; do
  case "$key" in 
    "$del") pattern="${pattern%?}";;  #backspace deletes the last character
        "") break;; #enter breaks the loop
         *) pattern="$pattern$key";; #everything else gets appended 
                                     #to the pattern string
  esac
  printScreen
done

clear
printSelected
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I tried using it, didn't work. Can you update the usage? is the script interactive? Actually the above answer solved the problem. But would like to know your approach also.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a try. I what sense did it not work? This is supposed to be a more universal approach -- like it doesn't hardcode `find`, but you provide find output on stdin, and it can be further piped into another commmand.

Comment: If you save the script as `terminalFilter`, do `chmod +x terminalFilter` and then `find | ./terminalFilter`, you should get interactively filtered find results and you should be able to reuse the filtered output easily.

Comment: Great. Its working. I didn't get the usage earlier. In this approach pattern appears in the bottom. How to check the files in parent directory or some other directory? Let me know the usage for that.

Comment: `find ../  | terminalFilter` . This just takes an initial set from `stdin`, does filter operations on that, and it makes the filtered result reusable (pipable further).  It's super easy to make it generate the set instead of using `stdin`, but I kind of like this concept.

Comment: Done. Got it. Thanks for liking the concept and helping me.

Comment: I love the concept. This is the sort of Unix-like "do one thing and do it well" utility I think we could use more of. IMO, this paradigm is highly underuitilized in GUI. I have a more extended version of that's got colors, and explicit subselections with arrows (about 200 lines of bash code). It could use left and right arrows for editing the pattern more effectively and an implementation of scrolling. I think it'd be easiest to do all of that in C++ with ncurses rather than bash, but I don't have time for it now.

Comment: I essentially wrote this for myself so I could do stuff like `vi \`git ls-files| filter\``, that is select files for a project for editing (or other type of processing) easily.

Answer (score 0):

`fzf` is a fast and powerful command-line fuzzy finder that exactly suits your needs.

Check it out here: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.

For your example, simple run `fzf` on the command line and it should work fine.